# How to add an indication in order to distinguish between productive and development version to every page of an apache server?

Tags: php, apache, http, apache2, webserver

I usually get confused when either the productive version or the development version of a web page is opened. For instance, I'm fooled when I edit the development code, being surprised that there are any changes in the productive version. Hopefully, I'm not the only one with this kind of problem.

My idea is to add a visible identifier to all pages running on the development apache server. It can be a different background color or something like a info box. I considered to change the favicon which would be the simplest solution, but something which attracts your attention immediately would be nicer.

I came up with the idea to check `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` on each page. But I don't want the server to process this check for every request! So, are there any ideas to add the mentioned identifier by the apache server?

P.S. the title might need to be rephrased!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this once. Usually I have some auxiliary functions that I include (in fact `require_once` at the beginning) in every page (file) that I use. You can do this there by setting a variable (or define a constant) and check it when you output HTML `BODY` tag by changing STYLE='background-color: ...' or something like that.

I think that this check by $_SERVER is not that much more processing effort as any other statement in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

> I came up with the idea to check $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] on each page. But I don't want the server to process this check for every request!

A string comparison has little to no impact. You must have some application entry point (a `include('init.php')` or so, or when using rewrites your `index.php` for example).

There you can simply do something like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == 'development') {
    $template['headerColor'] = 'green';
} else {
    $template['headerColor'] = 'red';
}
```

Comment: sry I don't get your point. When my Apache is running on localhost, I can just check `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1'`

Comment: I reckon that there must be another better solution as I don't want to add this check in every file. Yeah lazy.. I know ;)

Comment: @LongHoang that's what I said: _"You must have some application entry point"_, a single file that is loaded for each request, (or) for example a config file. Just put it in there.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you add - $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']=='127...' or include('init.php'). You must add **something** to every file.